# Separating Strings with different lengths with SAS

Tags: string, sas, data-manipulation

Lets say I have data Such as:

```
Score
6.2/30
10/30
19/30
3.4/30
```

I want to separate the data so that one column will be like 6.2 and the other one would be like 30
So something like

```
Score(1st column):             
6.2                    
10     

Out of(2nd Column):
30
```

Currently my Data code looks something like this:

```
DATA grades;
SET Work.grades;
STRING1=grades_MMSE_Score_on_admit;
TEST3 = SUBSTR(STRING1,1,3);
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=grades;
VAR TEST3;
RUN;
```

I can get it to separate but the problem is the ending position is different for data points that have decimals. How do I deal with data such as this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SCAN()` function.

```
score=scan(grades_MMSE_Score_on_admit,1,'/');
out_of=scan(grades_MMSE_Score_on_admit,2,'/');
```

But you probably want to convert them to numbers.

```
score=input(scan(grades_MMSE_Score_on_admit,1,'/'),32.);
out_of=input(scan(grades_MMSE_Score_on_admit,2,'/'),32.);
```